# Match two columns by searching along the column; both columns in same dataframe

Tags: r

I am employing RStudio. I have the following toy model:

```
df <- data.frame("Name1" = c("JPMorgan", "BMO", "Citibank", "Barclays", "Deutsche", "Chase", "HSBC", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".","."), "Name2" = c("JPMorgan and Chase","SEFCU Union","Wells Fargo Commercial Bank","Bank of America", "Citibank LLC","Charles Schwab", "Barclays", "HSBC Holdings PLc",  "Wall Bank Holdings", "Chase Manhattan Bank", "TD Bank", "Ally Bank", "Goldman Sachs", "M&T Bank", "Key Bank", "Royal Bank of Canada", "Bank of Montreal BMO", "US Bancorp", "Capital One", "BNY Mellon"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to create a third column called `df$matched` wherein each entry from `Name1` searches through the whole column `Name2`, and produces an output of 1 if the string is present partially in `Name2`, and a 0 if it is not present.

My current approach of using rowwise mutate is producing a 1:1 match.

My desired output would be a new column with:
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Thank you. A little more specifically, since JPMorgan is a part of JPMorgan and Chase, the output should be 1 for it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment, I'm assuming that you want to count any complete string from `Name1` contained in `Name2`. You can then use `pmatch()` for partial string matching and convert the result to logical using `as.logical()`. If you'd like `0` s and `1`s instead of `FALSE` and `TRUE`, just add another as.numeric():

```
df$matched <- as.numeric(as.logical(pmatch(df$Name1, df$Name2, nomatch = 0, duplicates.ok = TRUE)))
```

Comment: This works for me.
Instead of logical, if I wanted a binary 1 or 0?

Comment: Just add another as.numeric(). I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `stringr::str_detect`. It gives a different answer for "BMO" than the `pmatch` solution.

```
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")

has_match <- function(name, candidates) {
  if (name == ".")
    FALSE
  else
    any(str_detect(candidates, name))
}

df <- df %>% # Add the new columns. Although first you should probably decide on
             # which partial matching algorithm you want to use.
  mutate(match = sapply(Name1, has_match, Name2)) %>%
  mutate(match2 = pmatch(Name1, Name2, nomatch = 0, duplicates.ok = TRUE) > 0)
df
#       Name1                       Name2 match match2
# 1  JPMorgan          JPMorgan and Chase  TRUE   TRUE
# 2       BMO                 SEFCU Union  TRUE  FALSE
# 3  Citibank Wells Fargo Commercial Bank  TRUE   TRUE
# 4  Barclays             Bank of America  TRUE   TRUE
# 5  Deutsche                Citibank LLC FALSE  FALSE
# 6     Chase              Charles Schwab  TRUE   TRUE
# 7      HSBC                    Barclays  TRUE   TRUE
```

The difference for BMO is that it appears in "Bank of Montreal BMO" -- not at the start of the full name string. In all the other cases the match occurs at the start.

Comment: when you use mutate, match and match2 only show as results in the tibble. They do not get added to the dataframe as columns. How do you add them to df?

Comment: To add the new columns, rather than to just print them out, use `df <- df %>% ...` or `df = df %>% ...` where `...` stands in for the rest of the mutate statements. I printed them out because I wanted to show the difference between the two string matching algorithms. They are not the same. Do you want BMO to get TRUE or FALSE?